# Controlling Task execution order with ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I have a process which delegates asynch tasks to a pool of threads.  I need to ensure that certain tasks are executed in order.
So for example

Tasks arrive in order

Tasks  a1, b1, c1, d1 , e1, a2, a3, b2, f1

Tasks can be executed in any order except where there is a natural dependancy, so a1,a2,a3 must be processed in that order by either allocating to the same thread or blocking these until I know the previous a# task was completed.

Currently it doesn't use the Java Concurrency package, but I'm considering changing to take avantage of the thread management.

Does anyone have a similar solution or suggestions of how to achieve this

Answer (score 20):

I write own Executor that warrants task ordering for tasks with same key. It uses map of queues for order tasks with same key. Each keyed task execute next task with the same key.

This solution don't handle *RejectedExecutionException* or other exceptions from delegated Executor! So delegated Executor should be "unlimited".

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

/**
* This Executor warrants task ordering for tasks with same key (key have to implement hashCode and equal methods correctly).
*/
public class OrderingExecutor implements Executor{

    private final Executor delegate;
    private final Map<Object, Queue<Runnable>> keyedTasks = new HashMap<Object, Queue<Runnable>>();

    public OrderingExecutor(Executor delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        // task without key can be executed immediately
        delegate.execute(task);
    }

    public void execute(Runnable task, Object key) {
        if (key == null){ // if key is null, execute without ordering
            execute(task);
            return;
        }

        boolean first;
        Runnable wrappedTask;
        synchronized (keyedTasks){
            Queue<Runnable> dependencyQueue = keyedTasks.get(key);
            first = (dependencyQueue == null);
            if (dependencyQueue == null){
                dependencyQueue = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
                keyedTasks.put(key, dependencyQueue);
            }

            wrappedTask = wrap(task, dependencyQueue, key);
            if (!first)
                dependencyQueue.add(wrappedTask);
        }

        // execute method can block, call it outside synchronize block
        if (first)
            delegate.execute(wrappedTask);

    }

    private Runnable wrap(Runnable task, Queue<Runnable> dependencyQueue, Object key) {
        return new OrderedTask(task, dependencyQueue, key);
    }

    class OrderedTask implements Runnable{

        private final Queue<Runnable> dependencyQueue;
        private final Runnable task;
        private final Object key;

        public OrderedTask(Runnable task, Queue<Runnable> dependencyQueue, Object key) {
            this.task = task;
            this.dependencyQueue = dependencyQueue;
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                task.run();
            } finally {
                Runnable nextTask = null;
                synchronized (keyedTasks){
                    if (dependencyQueue.isEmpty()){
                        keyedTasks.remove(key);
                    }else{
                        nextTask = dependencyQueue.poll();
                    }
                }
                if (nextTask!=null)
                    delegate.execute(nextTask);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for that. I'll use this implantation, but I really don't know how this is not marked as the final answer for the question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. One observation (in 2022 :)) is that we could use ConcurrentHashMap for keyedTasks and ConcurrentLinkedQueue for  dependencyQueue instead and remove the synchronized block all together.

Answer (score 14):

When I've done this in the past I've usually had the ordering handled by a component which then submits callables/runnables to an Executor.

Something like.

- Got a list of tasks to run, some with dependencies
- Create an Executor and wrap with an ExecutorCompletionService
- Search all tasks, any with no dependencies, schedule them via the completion service
- Poll the completion service
- As each task completes

  - Add it to a "completed" list
  - Reevaluate any waiting tasks wrt to the "completed list" to see if they are "dependency complete".  If so schedule them
  - Rinse repeat until all tasks are submitted/completed

The completion service is a nice way of being able to get the tasks as they complete rather than trying to poll a bunch of Futures.  However you will probably want to keep a `Map<Future, TaskIdentifier>` which is populated when a task is schedule via the completion service so that when the completion service gives you a completed Future you can figure out which `TaskIdentifier` it is.

If you ever find yourself in a state where tasks are still waiting to run, but nothing is running and nothing can be scheduled then your have a circular dependency problem.

Comment: Can you please give us some example

Answer (score 3):

When you submit a `Runnable` or `Callable` to an `ExecutorService` you receive a `Future` in return. Have the threads that depend on a1 be passed a1's `Future` and call `Future.get()`. This will block until the thread completes.

So:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executor.newFixedThreadPool(5);
Runnable a1 = ...
final Future f1 = exec.submit(a1);
Runnable a2 = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    f1.get();
    ... // do stuff
  }
}
exec.submit(a2);
```

and so on.

Comment: I don't think this will work with a fixed thread pool, as the threads could all block on `f1.get()` at once and be deadlocked.

Comment: Tune the size of the pool as appropriate.

Comment: Cached thread pool has its own problem. Thread creation can get out of control if you submit too much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), but it will use only one thread to execute your tasks. Another option is to use CountDownLatch. Here is a simple example:

```
public class Main2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final CountDownLatch cdl1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch cdl2 = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch cdl3 = new CountDownLatch(1);

    List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
    list.add(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Task 1");

            // inform that task 1 is finished
            cdl1.countDown();
        }
    });

    list.add(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // wait until task 1 is finished
            try {
                cdl1.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Task 2");

            // inform that task 2 is finished
            cdl2.countDown();
        }
    });

    list.add(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // wait until task 2 is finished
            try {
                cdl2.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Task 3");

            // inform that task 3 is finished
            cdl3.countDown();
        }
    });

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        es.submit(list.get(i));
    }

    es.shutdown();
    es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create your own executor, call it OrderedExecutor, and create an array of encapsulated ThreadPoolExecutor objects, with 1 thread per internal executor. You then supply a mechanism for choosing one of the internal objects, eg, you can do this by providing an interface that the user of your class can implement:

```
executor = new OrderedExecutor( 10 /* pool size */, new OrderedExecutor.Chooser() {
  public int choose( Runnable runnable ) {
     MyRunnable myRunnable = (MyRunnable)runnable;
     return myRunnable.someId();
  });

executor.execute( new MyRunnable() );
```

The implementation of OrderedExecutor.execute() will then use the Chooser to get an int, you mod this with the pool size, and that's your index into the internal array. The idea being that "someId()" will return the same value for all the "a's", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I created an OrderingExecutor for this problem. If you pass the same key to to method execute() with different runnables, the execution of the runnables with the same key will be in the order the execute() is called and will never overlap.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

/**
 * Special executor which can order the tasks if a common key is given.
 * Runnables submitted with non-null key will guaranteed to run in order for the same key.
 *
 */
public class OrderedExecutor {

    private static final Queue<Runnable> EMPTY_QUEUE = new QueueWithHashCodeAndEquals<Runnable>(
            new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>());

    private ConcurrentMap<Object, Queue<Runnable>> taskMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Queue<Runnable>>();
    private Executor delegate;
    private volatile boolean stopped;

    public OrderedExecutor(Executor delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void execute(Runnable runnable, Object key) {
        if (stopped) {
            return;
        }

        if (key == null) {
            delegate.execute(runnable);
            return;
        }

        Queue<Runnable> queueForKey = taskMap.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> {
            v.add(runnable);
            return v;
        });
        if (queueForKey == null) {
            // There was no running task with this key
            Queue<Runnable> newQ = new QueueWithHashCodeAndEquals<Runnable>(new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>());
            newQ.add(runnable);
            // Use putIfAbsent because this execute() method can be called concurrently as well
            queueForKey = taskMap.putIfAbsent(key, newQ);
            if (queueForKey != null)
                queueForKey.add(runnable);
            delegate.execute(new InternalRunnable(key));
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        stopped = true;
        taskMap.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Own Runnable used by OrderedExecutor.
     * The runnable is associated with a specific key - the Queue&lt;Runnable> for this
     * key is polled.
     * If the queue is empty, it tries to remove the queue from taskMap. 
     *
     */
    private class InternalRunnable implements Runnable {

        private Object key;

        public InternalRunnable(Object key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                // There must be at least one task now
                Runnable r = taskMap.get(key).poll();
                while (r != null) {
                    r.run();
                    r = taskMap.get(key).poll();
                }
                // The queue emptied
                // Remove from the map if and only if the queue is really empty
                boolean removed = taskMap.remove(key, EMPTY_QUEUE);
                if (removed) {
                    // The queue has been removed from the map,
                    // if a new task arrives with the same key, a new InternalRunnable
                    // will be created
                    break;
                } // If the queue has not been removed from the map it means that someone put a task into it
                  // so we can safely continue the loop
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Special Queue implementation, with equals() and hashCode() methods.
     * By default, Java SE queues use identity equals() and default hashCode() methods.
     * This implementation uses Arrays.equals(Queue::toArray()) and Arrays.hashCode(Queue::toArray()).
     *
     * @param <E> The type of elements in the queue.
     */
    private static class QueueWithHashCodeAndEquals<E> implements Queue<E> {

        private Queue<E> delegate;

        public QueueWithHashCodeAndEquals(Queue<E> delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        public boolean add(E e) {
            return delegate.add(e);
        }

        public boolean offer(E e) {
            return delegate.offer(e);
        }

        public int size() {
            return delegate.size();
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return delegate.isEmpty();
        }

        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            return delegate.contains(o);
        }

        public E remove() {
            return delegate.remove();
        }

        public E poll() {
            return delegate.poll();
        }

        public E element() {
            return delegate.element();
        }

        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return delegate.iterator();
        }

        public E peek() {
            return delegate.peek();
        }

        public Object[] toArray() {
            return delegate.toArray();
        }

        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
            return delegate.toArray(a);
        }

        public boolean remove(Object o) {
            return delegate.remove(o);
        }

        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
            return delegate.containsAll(c);
        }

        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
            return delegate.addAll(c);
        }

        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
            return delegate.removeAll(c);
        }

        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
            return delegate.retainAll(c);
        }

        public void clear() {
            delegate.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof QueueWithHashCodeAndEquals)) {
                return false;
            }
            QueueWithHashCodeAndEquals<?> other = (QueueWithHashCodeAndEquals<?>) obj;
            return Arrays.equals(toArray(), other.toArray());
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.hashCode(toArray());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Habanero-Java library](https://wiki.rice.edu/confluence/display/PARPROG/HJ+Library), there is a concept of data-driven tasks which can be used to express dependencies between tasks and avoid thread-blocking operations. Under the covers Habanero-Java library uses the JDKs ForkJoinPool (i.e. an ExecutorService).

For example, your use case for tasks A1, A2, A3, ... could be expressed as follows:

```
HjFuture a1 = future(() -> { doA1(); return true; });
HjFuture a2 = futureAwait(a1, () -> { doA2(); return true; });
HjFuture a3 = futureAwait(a2, () -> { doA3(); return true; });
```

Note that a1, a2, and a3 are just references to objects of type HjFuture and can be maintained in your custom data structures to specify the dependencies as and when the tasks A2 and A3 come in at runtime.

There are some [tutorial slides available](https://wiki.rice.edu/confluence/display/PARPROG/Habanero-Java%3a+Multicore+Programming+for+the+Masses).
You can find further documentation as [javadoc](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~vs3/hjlib/doc/), [API summary](https://wiki.rice.edu/confluence/display/PARPROG/API+Documentation) and [primers](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~vs3/hjlib/code/edu/rice/hj/example/primers/).

Answer (score 0):

I have written my won executor service which is sequence aware. It sequences the tasks which contain certain related reference and currently inflight.

You can go through the implementation at https://github.com/nenapu/SequenceAwareExecutorService