# How to specify the exact execution order of asynchronous calls in Scala unit tests?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, execution

I have written many different unit tests for futures in Scala.
All asynchronous calls use an execution context.
To make sure that the asynchronous calls are always executed in the same order, I need to delay some tasks which is rather difficult and slows the tests down.
The executor might still (depending on its implementation) complete some tasks before others.

What is the best way to test concurrent code with a specific execution order? For example, I have the following test case:

```
"firstSucc" should "complete the final future with the first one" in {
    val executor = getExecutor
    val util = getUtil
    val f0 = util.async(executor, () => 10)
    f0.sync
    val f1 = util.async(executor, () => { delay(); 11 })
    val f = f0.firstSucc(f1)
    f.get should be(10)
  }
```

where delay is `def delay() = Thread.sleep(4000)` and `sync` synchronizes the future (calls `Await.ready(future, Duration.Inf)`).
That's how I want to make sure that f0 is already completed and f1 completes AFTER f0. It is not enough that f0 is completed since `firstSucc` could be shuffling the futures. Therefore, f1 should be delayed until after the check of `f.get`.

Another idea is to create futures from promises and complete them at a certain point in time:

```
  "firstSucc" should "complete the final future with the first one" in {
    val executor = getExecutor
    val util = getUtil
    val f0 = util.async(executor, () => 10)
    val p = getPromise
    val f1 = p.future
    val f = f0.firstSucc(f1)
    f.get should be(10)
    p.trySuccess(11)
  }
```

Is there any easier/better approach to define the execution order? Maybe another execution service where one can configure the order of submitted tasks?
For this specific case it might be enough to delay the second future until after the result has been checked but in some cases ALL futures have to be completed but in a certain order.

The complete code can be found here: https://github.com/tdauth/scala-futures-promises

The test case is part of this class: https://github.com/tdauth/scala-futures-promises/blob/master/src/test/scala/tdauth/futuresandpromises/AbstractFutureTest.scala

This question might be related since Scala can use Java Executor Services: [Controlling Task execution order with ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153663/controlling-task-execution-order-with-executorservice)

Comment: Why do you think that testing concurrent code with delays and specific execution order is a good idea in the first place? The bugs in concurrently running code usually occur exactly *because* of the unexpected order of events and failures to synchronize the memory between the threads. Stuff like `Thread.sleep(4000)` would make the tests mostly useless, because the JVM might decide to synchronize the memory after a while, even without any explicit synchronization in the code, which would mean that even broken code can easily pass your tests.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin "the bugs occur because of the unexpected order" - yes, but it may still be useful to write a test, that ensures there are no bugs in case events happen in a _specific_ order

Comment: @Dima Then one should separate the logic that one wants to test from the concurrent evaluation strategy, implement a separate sequential deterministic interpreter, and test the logic with that. Only then should one switch to a concurrent implementation, and test that it also works as expected (regardless of execution order, and without artificial delays). Implementing everything with concurrency and futures first, and then trying to impose delays and a specific order looks more like an attempt to make a river flow against the gravity.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes, that's all right. The question is how to test that the original implementation didn't break after you switch it to concurrent.

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea but I need to test cases where there is a specific order of events. Otherwise, I cannot expect a certain result. Maybe mocking the futures would help, I don't know.

Comment: @Baradé no, mocking the futures isn't a good idea. _But_ you can always mock the executor, to make it execute your futures in the calling thread. That kinda circumvents the idea of testing the concurrent behavior, but does make the test completely deterministic.

Comment: Well, the test has to be deterministic to expect certain results.

Comment: @Baradé it doesn't _have to_ be deterministic, only results do. That's Andrey's point: the results produced by your code should not depend on the order of execution.

Comment: Maybe the best way to define the test would be without any executor at all and to use promises to complete the futures at a certain point or not complete them at all.

Comment: Now you sound like you are trying to test future transformations ... that don't really need to be tested (by you). Just use library functions.

Comment: That's what I am doing here but the transformation firstSucc is not a library function, it is part of the project. Hence, the executor is probably unnecessary and a test with a promise would be enough.

Comment: @Baradé consider using `Future.firstCompletedOf`

Answer (score 1):

For most simple cases, I'd say a single threaded executor should be enough - if you  start your futures one-by-one, they'll be executed serially, and complete in the same order.

But it looks like your problem is actually more complex than what you are describing: you are not only looking for a way to ensure one future *completes* later than the other, but in general, to make a sequence of arbitrary events happen in a particular order. Fr example, the snippet in your question, verifies that the second future *starts* after the first one *completes* (I have not idea what the `delay` is for in that case btw).

You can use `eventually` to wait for a particular event to occur before continuing:

```
   val f = Future(doSomething) 
   eventually { 
      someFlag shouldBe true
   }
   val f1 = Future(doSomethingElse) 
   eventually { 
      f.isCompleted shouldBe true
   }
   someFlag = false   
   eventually { 
      someFlag shouldBe true
   }

   f1.futureValue shoudlBe false
```

Comment: thx, eventually looks interesting but you are right. Since I pass one uncompleted future to f0.firstSucc(f1) I need to make sure that f0 does always complete before f1.

Comment: @Baradé doesn't `f0.sync` do just that?

Comment: It does but the solution should also work when firstSucc shuffles the futures for example. Therefore, it would be important that f1 is delayed until after the test. I have added another solution with a promise. Note that the solutions in the questions do already work but I am looking for a cleaner/more general way to define the order.